# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method, causing app to crash

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I'm particularly new to this field. I'm trying to create a login page using fragments and it crashed when I tried to run it. I checked the logcat, turns out its a NullPointerException. It highlighted the error here:

```
register = (Button) findViewById(R.id.RegisterUser);
register.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Here is my code

this is mainactivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private TextView register;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        register = (Button) findViewById(R.id.RegisterUser);
        register.setOnClickListener(this);

        ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

        AuthenticationPagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new 
        AuthenticationPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        pagerAdapter.addFragmet(new LoginFragment());
        pagerAdapter.addFragmet(new RegisterFragment());
        viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
    }

    public void onClick(View v){
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.RegisterUser:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, RegisterUser.class));
            break;
        }
    }

    class AuthenticationPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private ArrayList<Fragment> fragmentList = new ArrayList<>();

        public AuthenticationPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int i) {
            return fragmentList.get(i);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return fragmentList.size();
        }

        void addFragmet(Fragment fragment) {
            fragmentList.add(fragment);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It suggests `register` is `null`, which would indicate that `findViewById` did not find your button.

Comment: show `activity_main.xml` file. there is no `RegisterUser` button for shure and you are trying to find it with `findViewById`, which results `null`

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted your whole exception trace here.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you define the global field `private TextView register;` but you want to cast it to Button `register = (Button) findViewById(R.id.RegisterUser);`

Please check your XML file and make sure what's your element TextView or Button.

Answer (score 0):

can you please check your `activity_main.xml` file
check into that is a `Button` or `Textview`